# Error al serializar LocalDateTime con OpenAPI Generator

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, openapi

Estoy usando OpenAPI Generator para crear un cliente Rest, pero cuando intento hacer una petición POST se serializa LocalDateTime como un arreglo entero, así

```json
{
  "startDate": [ 2019, 11, 13, 0, 0 ],
  "endDate": [ 2020, 12, 31, 0, 0 ]
}
```

Estoy esperando este resultado, en formato ISO

```json
{
  "startDate": "2019-11-13T00:00",
  "endDate": "2020-12-31T00:00"
}
```

Mi configuración de gradle es:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.3'
  classpath 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:4.2.3'
}

task generateClientDS(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
  inputSpec = "$rootDir/specifications/client-ds.yaml".toString()
  outputDir = "$rootDir".toString()
  generatorName = 'java'
  library = 'resttemplate'
  apiPackage = 'com.example.gen.clients.clientds.api'
  modelPackage = 'com.example.gen.clients.clientds.dto'
  modelNameSuffix = 'DTO'
  configOptions = [
          hideGenerationTimestamp: 'true',
          dateLibrary: 'java8'
  ]
  typeMappings = [
          OffsetDateTime: 'java.time.LocalDateTime'
  ]
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Incluso he intentado con un been pero no funciona, ¿alguna idea de lo que está mal?